# Error: No certificate for team 'TJPFHY739U' matching 'world unknown' found:

Tags: react-native, azure-devops

[command]/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release -workspace /Users/vsts/agent/2.148.2/work/1/s/ios/community_app.xcworkspace -scheme community_app -allowProvisioningUpdates clean build CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=world unknown PROVISIONING_PROFILE=cad7fbfe-78e7-48a4-a2aa-24fd2337df34 PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER= | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/xcpretty -r junit --no-color
▸ Clean Succeeded

❌  error: No certificate for team 'TJPFHY739U' matching 'world unknown' found: Select a different signing certificate for CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY, a team that matches your selected certificate, or switch to automatic provisioning. (in target 'community_app')

❌  error: Provisioning profile "P1" belongs to team "Enterprise Solutions, Inc.", which does not match the selected team "TJPFHY739U". (in target 'community_app')

❌  error: community_appTests does not support provisioning profiles. community_appTests does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile P1 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'community_appTests')

Comment: It seems you haven't generated the right certificate and provisioning certificate

Comment: I am using Azure DevOps for build ios project and publish it to app store. But the problem is how to generate certificate for particular app id. I want to automate the whole process from build to deploy on App Store.

Comment: I don't know is it possible to automate or not. One of my colleague use this https://fastlane.tools/ automates the process.